# Usage of "embed"

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Suggest, please, correct usage of word `Embed`. Is what from two usages is correct? (and why)

> Editing is available only in **embedded** mode. **(Mode is embedded ?)**

or

> Editing is available only in **embed** mode. **(Mode is embed ?)**

Comment: If you have more than one question, it's best to ask each as a separate question. That helps keep answers focussed, and doesn't discourage anyone from answering if they know the answer to one but not all of your questions.

Comment: @starsplusplus: thanks, I have separated my questions.

Comment: Because it's a name of a mode, it would be up to the person who named the mode, though in my opinion, "embedded" is more likely (and "embedding" is also possible). Also, it might be better to write *in Embedded mode* or *in the embedded mode*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Past tense of an adjective](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/18425/past-tense-of-an-adjective)

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Now I see it's a duplicate post, and interestingly in that post same source was used as mine for quotation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Embed** is by itself a verb, and it can't modify another noun. But in case of your sentence the word **embed** is supposed to modify/qualify a noun - **mode**. And hence a participle form of the verb - **embed** - is appropriate and correct.

There are two participle form - present participle and past participle.

So in your case it should be ***embedded mode***

**Usage Note for participle -**

> When the present participle (-ing from) is used, the noun it describes
>   is (or was) the performer of the activity named by the participle. 
>   For example, in the sentence *"The dog barks,"* **the dog** is the performer
>   of the action **(bark)**. *It is a **barking** dog*.
>
> When the past participle (-ed, -en form) is used, the noun it
>   describes is (or was) acted upon.  For example, in *The child is*
>   *frightened by the dog*, **the child** is the receiver of the action and is
>   described as *a **frightened** child*.

**[Source](http://rwc.hunter.cuny.edu/reading-writing/on-line/particip.html)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please add a source for the quotation?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName Source added :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case it looks like "embed" is being used as the *name* of the mode making it a noun, thus while "embed" is normally a verb - in this case it's being *used* like a noun that's being used like an adjective. That said - it should probably be capitalized.

You can do this with just about any word:

```
Editing is only available in Embed mode.
Prancing is only available in Pony mode.
Pushing is only available in Push mode.
```

On the other hand; if the mode itself *is* embedded in something then by all means call it an "embedded mode" since in that case you are describing the condition of the mode; it's embedded (within something else).